# No se puede conectar con el servidor web de desarrollo configurado

Tags: visual-studio-2015, webservice, iis

Hace unos días tuve que formatear mi computadora por unos problemas con Windows 10, al reinstalar Visual Studio 2015 y tratar de correr unos proyectos de servicios web, me lanza ese mensaje de error que desconozco completamente de qué se trate. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme con esto, me urgen esos servicios.

**Actualización**

[image: Cuadro de texto]

[image: Consola de salida]

Versión de IIS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización 2**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tienes el mensaje de error? No se visualiza en tu pregunta.

Comment: Sólo es un MessageBox que dice lo que dice el título de la pregunta

Comment: Te recomiendo poner los tags asociados a tu pregunta así como en el cuerpo de la pregunta poner las tecnologías utilizadas (IIS versión X, Visual Studio versión X etc), por ejemplo, como tags puedes poner IIS, Visual Studio o alguna otra que consideres relacionada a tu pregunta. Esto con el objetivo de identificar las tecnologías utilizadas y la comunidad te ayude de forma más inmediata. (Por cierto, [respondí a tu pregunta,](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27634/16841) valida que sea la solución

Comment: muchas gracias por este excelente aporte...

Comment: En mi caso, la solución fue cerrar la solución, eliminar del proyecto la carpeta oculta .vs, reconstruir y listo!

Comment: Solo tuve que poner en: * Opciones de Vista del explorador la pestaña "Mostrar Archivos y Carpetas Ocultas del Sistema"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a mi problema, es tan simple como borrar un archivo que se encuentra en:

> [proyecto].vs\applicationhost.config

Y con esto pude correr de nuevo mis servicios Web.

-Al momento de volver a correrlo , no encuentra el archivo que borre y vuelve a crearlo con la configuración correcta

Comment: Marca esta respuesta como aceptada usando el check verde del costado, de esta manera ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D

Answer (score 1):

En este caso, hay dos acciones a tomar:

1. Dar de alta el servicio como un WebSite en tu IIS local, el path del WebSite debe ser la misma ruta donde existe tu solución, esto con el objetivo de que al momento de hacer debug tome las DLLs más actualizadas.
2. Ejecutar Visual Studio con privilegios de administrador.

Comment: Actualizaré mi pregunta para que veas unas capturas de pantalla

Comment: Bien, ¿pudiste validar los dos puntos que te puse? Otro dato a revisar es la versión del pool, ¿qué versión estás utilizando?

Comment: Monté la carpeta y la convertí en un sitio web en el IIS, me da un error. (Actualizaré de nuevo) y siempre lo corro en modo de administrador.
Cómo puedo saber qué versión del pool tengo?

Comment: Si lo tienes en español, en el IIS despliega la lista del WebSite principal, dale clic derecho donde está tu servicio publicado, luego Administrar Aplicación, y luego dale clic en Configuración Avanzada, se te desplegará una ventana y la opción Grupo de Aplicacion te dirá la versión del pool utilizado

Comment: Allí dice el mismo nombre que tiene el WebService, además me despliega otras opciones

Comment: No te dice algo como: ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated ?

Comment: No, sólo aparecen: .NET 2.0, .NET 2.0 Classic, .NET 4.5, .NET4.5 Classic, Classic .NET AppPool, DefaultAppPool y el nombre del WebService

Comment: Hagamos lo siguiente. Entra a esta [liga](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6cw6cfs.aspx), te dirá cómo crear un directorio virtual desde el Visual Studio. 
Toma en cuenta los siguientes pasos solamente: 

To create a local IIS virtual directory for a Web Application Project
In Visual Studio, open an existing Web application project, or create a new one.
In the Project menu, click Properties, and then click Web.
Click Use Local IIS Web server.
Enter a URL for the project, and then click Create Virtual Directory.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en cuanto pueda lo revisaré y te comento cómo me fue.

Comment: Con la actualización 2 ya vi cuál es el problema, debes hacer dos cosas. Debes cerrar Visual Studio, al ícono dale clic derecho y luego en Ejecutar como Administrador. La segunda es, la carpeta dónde reside el WebSite dale permisos de lectura y escritura a todos los usuarios. Estoy seguro que con esto se soluciona tu problema

Comment: Hice lo que me comentas pero no funcionó, sigue arrojando el mismo error

Comment: ¿Dando permisos a todos los usuarios y ejecutando el VS como administrador tampoco te funcionó?

Comment: No funcionó. Acabo de publicar una respuesta que fue lo que solucionó mi problema

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que reporta Microsoft sobre este error:

- Se intentó depurar una aplicación web de .NET que se copió en un
  equipo diferente, se cambió de nombre manualmente o se movió.
- No hay conexiones IIS suficientes. Para obtener más información sobre
  cómo implementar un sitio web en IIS, vea Crear un sitio web.
- Si intenta depurar una aplicación ASP.NET, vea Publicar en IIS para
  obtener instrucciones sobre la implementación en un equipo remoto que
  ejecuta IIS 8 o superior, o Depuración ASP.NET remota en un equipo
  remoto de IIS 7.5 para obtener instrucciones sobre la implementación
  en un equipo remoto que ejecuta IIS 7.5.

Fuente: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0y3b8byc.aspx

Comment: Imagino que es relacionado al primer punto que menciona la documentación, pero, ¿cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: En realidad ¿cual sería la solución a lo que pregunta el OP de acuerdo a esta información?, revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Como añadidura os cuento todo el proceso realizado y el cual en mi caso hizo que funcionara. Yo intente todas las respuestas dadas y ninguna me funciono.

Incluso reinicie el Visual Studio 2017, el equipo, cambie entre IIS Express a IIS Local (en la configuración del proyecto),... pero nada...

Finalmente probe a

Borrar [proyecto].vs\applicationhost.config
parar el IIS, a Iniciarlo y por si acaso a Reiniciarlo y finalmente me funcionó...

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, elimine la carpeta **.vs** que se encuentra dentro del proyecto y lo volví a correr y me funciono bien. por si algo creen copia de esa misma si no les funciona mi proceso. Éxitos.